# How to setup gtest in my visual studio project

Tags: c++, googletest

I simplify my question.
Should I create test files in related project or separate test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear for me, but here is a link that might help.
[Where do I place the Unit Testing source and expose the internal components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390171/where-do-i-place-the-unit-testing-source-and-expose-the-internal-components)